# React-Native: Render View From Javascript

Tags: android, react-native, autocompletetextview, native-module, react-native-native-module

So I am trying to use AutoCompleteTextView(for android) as a native module in react-native.

I drew inspiration from

https://github.com/nulrich/RCTAutoComplete.

So in the above library the author has defined custom cell for each AutoCompleteDropDownListItem.

I want to achieve something similar for android.

I want do define a callback(similar to renderItem as in FlatList for each DropDownListItem) to make things convenient.

Any help on the same would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use this library for android: https://github.com/mrlaessig/react-native-autocomplete-input

Comment: This is not something we are looking for, handling of the edge cases in this library is not the best. We would like to handle things natively. Thanks anyway.